# Delete Nth from last

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

If my linked list have 10000 nodes then how will I delete Nth node from the last without traversing again and again?

I traveled the linked list again and again in order to find length and then traversing and then deleting from the last, which leads to O(n) complexity each time.

Comment: Yes, that is expected. You can have an iteration with two pointers (one lagging behind by N steps), but that just hides a second iteration. Even if you keep track of the length, you still need that iteration to get to length-N, which still is O(n) on average.

Comment: Maintain a pointer to the end of the list? Keep track of the length of the list? I'm sure if you put your mind to it you can come up with ideas...

Comment: @topsail, neither of those ideas gives better time complexity.

Comment: The OP did not say he wanted to reduce time complexity - he only mentioned that he has O(n) complexity with the current approach. So, I don't assume anything!

Comment: @trincot If n = length of list, then "delete Nth from last" has complexity O(n-N) if keeping track of the length, and that's definitely a better time complexity than O(n) (except in the particular case where N is a constant).

Comment: @Stef, when I wrote "on average", I meant the average of taking valid values for N, given n. *"except in the case where N is constant"*, ... or where N=n/2, n/3, n/4, sqrt(n), log(n), ...etc.

Comment: Seems your approach only needs to travel the list twice. Once to get a count of nodes, then a second pass to get to the (count-n-1) node and set its next pointer to the (count-n+1) node. I assume it would then free the (count-n) node.

Answer (score 0):

```
let n = 10
if (head.next == null) {
        return head
    }
    let temp1 = head
    
    
    for (let i = 0; i<n ; i++) {
    if(temp1.next != null)
    {
          temp1 = temp1.next
    }
    else{
        return
    }
    }
    let temp2 = head
    for (let k = 0; temp1.next != null; k++) {
        temp1 = temp1.next
    temp2 = temp2.next
    }
    temp2.next = temp2.next.next
    return (head)
```

Here you do not need to traverse list twice,

In the above code first travers temp1 N number of element and then       travers both temp1 and temp2 till temp1 reach to end after that you      can delete Nth element from last node, without traversing again and      again.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single traversal, without finding the length of linked list.
Please refer the steps below:-

- Append a dummy node at the start, because in order to delete ith node we should have a pointer at i-1th node (case:- N = length of linked list)
- Take two pointers slow and fast, both pointing to dummy node
- Make fast pointer N steps ahead of slow pointer
- Now move slow and fast pointers together till the fast pointer reached end
- When fast pointer will be at the end of linked list, slow pointer will be pointing to (N-1)th node from end
- slow.next will be pointing to the node which is supposed to be deleted
- Now we can simply delete the Nth node by changing slow->next = slow->next->next

C++ code Sample:

```cpp
ListNode* removeNthFromEnd(ListNode* head, int n) {
    ListNode* dummy = new ListNode();
    dummy->next = head;
    ListNode* slow = dummy;
    ListNode* fast = dummy;
    int cnt = 0;
    while(cnt < n){
        fast = fast->next;
        cnt++;
    }
    
    while(fast->next != NULL){
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next;
    }
    slow->next = slow->next->next;
    return dummy->next;
}
```

Comment: Advancing two pointers through the list is the equivalent of two traversals with a single pointer. Also if dummy is allocated by new, doesn't it have to be freed using delete?